# Homestead vagrant up Parse error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I've been using Laravel 5.2 and recently started switching to Laravel 5.5. After configuring the etc/hosts and Homestead.yaml file, I encountered the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

As many have mentioned about PHP version problem, I thought once I have the homestead running, it should take care of it? As the doc said, in includesPHP 7.2
PHP 7.1
PHP 7.0
PHP 5.6 ([doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)). Moreover I have PHP 7.1.16 installed, which should meet the Laravel 5.5's requirement(PHP>=7.0.0). and the current configged php version is 7.0.8-2

I also updated virtual box to 5.2 and Vagrant to 2.1.1.
Also, when typing vagrant box list, I see this: laravel/homestead   (virtualbox, 0.5.0)

Please help, thanks!!

Comment: what is the configured php version ?

Comment: You mean the php in homestead? how should I check that? THX!

Comment: the easiest way to be sure to get the actual configured version is to put `phpinfo();die();` into index.php before all the other code. this will dump the php info and will give you the php version used

Comment: Thanks! This is what I got : PHP Version 7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
System Linux homestead 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64. So it's still php version problem...how should I upgrade it? should I download a brand new homestead by "vagrant box add laravel/homestead"? Is it going to overwrite the existing laravel/homestead?

Comment: actually, if the min requirement is >=7.0.0, this version should be fine right?

Comment: yes it should work fine. i'm not familiar with homestead so i don't know what to suggest next...